# Whats wrong with my JavaScript animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So i have this web-page to design and i want an image of the moon to rise-up from bottom of the screen to top. This is the HTML :

```
<body>
    <div id="Moon" onload="Moon()"></div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
#Moon{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    background: transparent url(../Img/Moon.SVG) no-repeat ;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and JavaScript for animation :

```
function Moon(){
    var Moon=document.getElementById("Moon");
    var yposition=Moon.style.top;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame(){
        if (Moon.style.top > 100) {
          yposition--; 
          Moon.style.top = yposition + 'px'; 
        } else {
          clearInterval(id);
        } 
        frame();
    }
}
```

but for some reasons the image of moon stays at the bottom of the page and doesn't move at all. any ideas?

Comment: can you give us demo from http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

you need to calculate top offset of the div using **moon.offsetTop**
and a div does not have a onload event so you will have to call your Moon() function either from script or from body onload event

```js
function Moon(){
    var moon=document.getElementById("Moon");
    
    var yposition= parseInt(moon.offsetTop) ;
  
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  
    function frame()
    {
        if (moon.offsetTop > 10) {
          yposition--; 
          document.getElementById("Moon").style.top = yposition + 'px'; 
        } else {
          clearInterval(id);
        } 
    } 
}
```

```css
#Moon{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 600px;
  background: transparent url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQh7mGmBMJ--wS711QkCEPHHS56jV15VmESttDbVLZPSI_FsMAyTQ") no-repeat ;
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<body onload="Moon()">
<div id="Moon"></div>
  </body>
```